# How can I remove frame like background in twentysixteen theme

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I remove frame like background in twentysixteen theme:

[image: i am talking about these borders around the page]

I have a wordpress blog with twentysixteen theme. Recently I tried to change background color but could not do it as I wanted.
I looked into css file but could not find codes for it.
Changing the body background changes the border color, but I don't want the background to be like border. How can I make it as a normal background?
Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css:

```
body:before,
body:after {
  display: none;
}
.site {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Or (clean solution) find this in style.css and remove it:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 44.375em) {
  body:not(.custom-background-image):before,
  body:not(.custom-background-image):after {
     background: inherit;
     content: "";
     display: block;
     height: 21px;
     left: 0;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 99;
```

}

```
@media screen and (min-width: 44.375em) {   
  .site {
    margin: 21px;   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the standard theme styles:

```
body {
    background: #1a1a1a;
}
.site {
    margin: 21px;
}
```